# Prefix path for FXML files in TornadoFX

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

Is there a way to provide a path for FXML files, used by *TornadoFX*, with using its convention `by fxml()`?

Normally, *TornadoFX* conventionally tries to locate FXML resources in `src/main/resources`, however, our application is large and this might now be the best idea. In our case, we would like to maintain the files in a subdirectory, i.e. `src/main/resources/fxml`.

We would like to set it up during application startup. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an FXML locator function to the framework so that you can override this to change the resource location. The declaration and default implementation looks like this:

```
var fxmlLocator: (component: UIComponent, location: String?) -> URL = { component, location ->
    val targetLocation = location ?: component.javaClass.simpleName + ".fxml"
    requireNotNull(component.resources.url(targetLocation)) { "FXML not found for ${component.javaClass} in $targetLocation" }
}
```

You can override this in `app.init()` for example, like this:

```
FX.fxmlLocator = { component, _ ->
    val targetLocation = "/fxml/${component.javaClass.simpleName}.fxml"
    requireNotNull(component.resources.url(targetLocation)) { "FXML not found for ${component.javaClass} in $targetLocation" }
}
```

However, if you go this route you must pay attention to your class names, as the same class name in different packages would look for the same resource in /fxml. Alternatively, change the implementation to observe the package names as well.

I'm committing the feature now, you can try it out tomorrow using the latest snapshot release from sonatype.

Comment: Decent, one word. Thank you.